# How can I sort table based on calculated column on the fly

Tags: sql, elasticsearch

I have table
[This table is obtained by sql query below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lEAij.png)

```
SELECT addressId, min(school), min(grocery)
FROM geo_address 
GROUP BY addressId 
ORDER BY min(grocery), min(school)
```

I added `min(school) + min(grocery)` as score to above query
[here is the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fcpl1.png)

I want to sort based on score(column added on the fly) but when I try it I get an error on the kibana console. The first error is => can not order by non grouped column[score]. To fix this I tried to group by score. Then I got another error => Cannot use an aggregate [MIN] for grouping. Please help me on ordering based on score.

Answer (score 0):

try doing a subquery

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT addressID, MIN(school) as school, MIN(grocery) as grocery
                FROM geo_address
                GROUP BY 1) t
ORDER BY addressid ASC, grocery ASC, school ASC;
```

Comment: The approach looks good. But the question was to sort by score. For addressid a subquery wouldn’t be necessary. Perhaps you want to revise your answer accordingly?

Comment: I used the approach. it is better but still there is problem. I can sort using grocery or school. But whenever I try to sort using score, problem arises. Is that something related to elasticsearch or sql related?

Comment: this is limitation of elasticsearch sql aggregations. So I can not do it unless the functionality is implemented at core of elasticsearch. So I will look for another strategy https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/85894#issuecomment-1099531925